# Condition check using choice in mule 4

Tags: dataweave, mule4

Am trying to check whether the Name filed is present in changed fields in below json data.

Input:

```
{
    "data": {
        "schema": "1vThoUjGykaw_VgT4Qu2eg",
        "payload": {
            "Job_Prev_Name__c": "C##-#7-00052 | Mule UT",
            "LastModifiedDate": "2020-09-03T06:52:08Z",
            "ChangeEventHeader": {
                "commitNumber": 10720388062229,
                "commitUser": "00570000001c9fmAAA",
                "sequenceNumber": 1,
                "entityName": "ATI_Job__c",
                "changeType": "UPDATE",
                "changedFields": [
                    "Name",
                    "LastModifiedDate",
                    "Job_Name__c",
                    "Job_Prev_Name__c"
                ],
                "changeOrigin": "com/salesforce/api/soap/49.0;client=SfdcInternalAPI/",
                "transactionKey": "00042924-3d1d-fae6-7d7a-1a3fbda54122",
                "commitTimestamp": 1599115928000,
                "recordIds": [
                    "a77V00000000vI4IAI"
                ]
            },
            "Job_Name__c": "Mule UV",
            "Name": "C##-#7-00052 | Mule UV"
        },
        "event": {
            "replayId": 1020702
        }
    },
    "channel": "/data/ATI_Job__ChangeEvent"
}
```

The condition am using now is

```
payload.data.payload.changedFields.Name?
```

But it is failing everytime. How can i achieve this condition check in choice connector?

Answer (score 0):

Your input json doesn't seem to be valid json. I modified it a bit to help you with the solution.

```
{
    "schema": "1vThoUjGykaw_VgT4Qu2eg",
    "payload": {
      "Job_Prev_Name__c": "C##-#7-00052 | Mule UT",
      "LastModifiedDate": "2020-09-03T06:52:08Z",
      "ChangeEventHeader": {
        "commitNumber": 10720388062229,
        "commitUser": "00570000001c9fmAAA",
        "sequenceNumber": 1,
        "entityName": "ATI_Job__c",
        "changeType": "UPDATE",
        "changedFields": [
          "Name",
          "LastModifiedDate",
          "Job_Name__c",
          "Job_Prev_Name__c"
        ],
        "changeOrigin": "com/salesforce/api/soap/49.0;client=SfdcInternalAPI/",
        "transactionKey": "00042924-3d1d-fae6-7d7a-1a3fbda54122",
        "commitTimestamp": 1599115928000,
        "recordIds": [
          "a77V00000000vI4IAI"
        ]
      }
    }
}
```

To verify that the changedFields array contains a value "Name" you can make use of the **contains** operator . As well since **payload** is a keyword and your input consist of that you need to wrap it in "".

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload."payload".ChangeEventHeader.changedFields contains "Name"
```

Comment: Actually, the payload root object is data, so, instead of payload."payload", it should be `payload.data.payload...` (the rest of the path seems correct). Could you please adjust it so your answer could be considered as correct? Thank you!

Comment: The json snippet posted initially is not a valid Json and thus I modified it a bit to help with the answer.

Comment: actually looks like it was just the initial `{` that was missing. I submitted an edit on the op.